# Facebook Unity SDK - App-to-User Notifications not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So based on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications) documentation I wanted to make a notification. I'm using this code:

```
public void SendNotification(string msg)
{
    FB.API("/me/notifications?access_token=here my app access token from access token tool&template=" + msg + "&href=www.google.com", HttpMethod.POST, result =>
    {
        Debug.Log(result.RawResult);
    });
}
```

Where "msg" is text from input field in Unity, when on href I give sample link, I will change it later. So Debug.Log(...) returns nothing, empty string, and I dont know why it doesn't work. When I testing this on Graph API Explorer with code:

```
user_id/notifications?template=TEST
```

and pasted app access token this works, I received notification on Facebook.

Can someone help me ? I really don't know reason why it doesn't work...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t use "me" for notifications, you have to use an App Scoped ID. The App Access Token does not have any relation to a specific User, "me" only makes sense with a User Token.

Comment: But "me " is just short hand for current logged Facebook user id , it's the same. Even when I tested , and instead of "me" I used current logged user id , still return empty string .

Comment: please read my answer again, the second sentence is very important. you MUST use an app token, it does NOT have a relation to the user, so you MUST use the app scoped user id instead of "me".

Comment: Still result is the same ( empty string ), when I'm using app scoped user ID or even real Facebook ID instead of me. I really don't know how to deal with it. Can you post example or something like that ?